# Python: Working with LinkedLists, can't add

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, linked-list

I am playing with linked lists for the first time, and I can't seem to understand why my add method isn't working.

Here is my code:

```
    class Node(object):

        def __init__(self, datain):
            self.data = datain
            self.next = None

        def getData(self):
            return self.data

        def getNext(self):
            return self.next

        def setData(self, newdata):
            self.data = newdata

        def setNext(self, newnext):
            self.data = newnext




    class UnorderedList(object): # also known as linked list

        def __init__(self):
            self.head = None

        def isEmpty(self):
            return self.head == None

        def add(self, item):
            temp = Node(item)
            temp.setNext(self.head)
            self.head = temp

        def size(self):
            current = self.head
            count = 0
            while current != None:
                count = count + 1
                current = current.getNext()
            return count

        def search(self, item):
            current = self.head
            found = False
            while current != None and not found:
                if current.getData == item:
                    found = True
                else:
                    current = current.getNext()
            return found

mylist = UnorderedList()

print mylist.size()
mylist.add(6)
print mylist.size()
mylist.add(9)
print mylist.size()
```

But I am not getting the desired outcome, this is what my terminal is displaying:

```
$ python linkedlist.py
0
1
1
```

The add method seems to not be working, but I can't figure out why. For reference, I have been using [this](http://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/pythonds/BasicDS/ImplementinganUnorderedListLinkedLists.html) to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
   def setNext(self, newnext):
        self.data = newnext
```

with:

```
   def setNext(self, newnext):
        self.next = newnext
```